# One statement to select data from two MySQL tables. Show name instead of/by ID

Tags: java, mysql

I have 2 tables

The table .issues looks like this:

```
id tracker_id project_id    
22       1       218
```

In the second table .trackers:

```
id    name    
1     Error
```

Is it possible to make one Select request to receive back the result with names of trackers instead of/with their ids? I need it to simplify the Java Request.

I want to get smth like this:

```
 id  (tracker_id) project_id tracker_name
 22  (1)           218        Error
```

I tried this, but I know it doesn't make much sense:

```
Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet ticketsRows = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM issues 
WHERE tracker_id IN (SELECT id FROM trackers)");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the `trackers` table and select the `name` column from that table instead the `tracker_id`

```
SELECT i.id, t.name as tracker_name, i.project_id
FROM issues i
JOIN trackers t on i.tracker_id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to :
SELECT i.id, i.tracker_id, i.project_id, t.name AS tracker_name
FROM issues i
JOIN trackers t on i.tracker_id = t.id

Answer (score -1):

this would give you exact answer to your question --

```
SELECT IS.ID, IS.tracker_id  ,IS.project_id ,  TR.tracker_name
FROM issues IS , tracker TR
where 
 IS.tracker_id = TR.id
```

Comment: Please don't encourage to use the old implicit join syntax any more.